# AzurePipeline GitVersion step not finding the config.yaml

Tags: azure-pipelines, gitversion

I've run out of idea trying to get my azure pipeline to work.
I have 2 repositories, one for the pipelines templates and one for my project.
Idea is to have generic pipelines ready to use in my projects just by referencing them.

## "Pipelines" repository

The folder structure is :

- commonLibrary

  - template.yaml
- version

  - gitVersion.yaml
  - config.yaml

### template.yaml

```
stages:
- stage: build 
  displayName: "Build"
  jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      submodules: true
      fetchDepth: 0 # https://github.com/GitTools/actions/blob/main/docs/examples/azure/gitversion/execute/usage-examples.md
      fetchTags: false

    - template: ../version/gitVersion.yaml@pipelines
```

### gitVersion.yaml

```
steps:
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      displayName: Install GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '5.x'

    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      displayName: Determine Version
      inputs:
        useConfigFile: true
        configFilePath: ./config.yaml
```

### config.yaml

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
branches:
  feature:
    regex: ^feature[\/]
    tag: alpha
  main:
    regex: ^main$
    tag: beta
  release:
    regex: ^release[\/]
    tag: ''
```

## "MicroService" repository

This is my microservice code, it contains an azure-pipelines.yaml file at the root of the repository:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipelines
      type: git
      name: Evently/Pipelines

stages:
  - template: commonLibrary/template.yaml@pipelines
```

Despite everything looking correct, when the pipeline runs, it fails "Determine Version" task.
Here is the output :

> ##[error]Error: GitVersion configuration file not found at /home/vsts/work/1/s/config.yaml

I tried many different path ./config.yaml, config.yaml, config.yaml@pipelines, version/config.yaml, ./version/config.yaml etc...

What am I missing ?
Thank you

Comment: It would be great if you did it with `tree` command.

Comment: Oh. Are you trying to access different directory with `..`? It would not work, as it is not checked out.

You need another checkout there.

Comment: @ravenwing Im trying to access the config.yaml file which in the same location as gitVersion.yaml.
The thing is, they are both in a repository called "pipeline"

I did something messy and fast but yeah i'll definitly go for tree once I get it to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't check out the "`Pipelines`" repository in your pipeline. So, it cannot find the `config.yaml` file.  I added `checkout: pipelines` step in the `template.yaml` and can make it work with the following yaml.

#### template.yaml

```
stages:
- stage: build 
  displayName: "Build"
  jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      submodules: true
      fetchDepth: 0 # https://github.com/GitTools/actions/blob/main/docs/examples/azure/gitversion/execute/usage-examples.md
      fetchTags: false
    - checkout: pipelines
    - bash:  tree
    - template: ../version/gitVersion.yaml@pipelines
```

#### gitVersion.yaml

```
steps:
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      displayName: Install GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '5.x'
    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      displayName: Determine Version
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MicroService/'
        useConfigFile: true
        configFilePath: './Pipelines/version/config.yaml'
```

Please note that when we check out multiple repositories in the pipeline, the source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of `s` in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. So, the "`MicroService`" repository is in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MicroService/` and the "`Pipelines`" repository is in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Pipelines`. I added the `bash: tree` task to print out the  file structure.

Here is my test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you saved me from a few hours of headache.
I appreciate the detailed explanation as Im a bit new to AzPipelines
Thank's again!